# Bootstrap collapse: no closing animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing Bootstrap collapse alongside `ng-repeat`.  I have two implementations of it where in one, both animations are working, and in the other, only the open animation is working.  The closing of a collapsible element doesn't animate, it just instantly shrinks.  The difference between the two implementations is that the working one has no nested `ng-repeat` directives, whereas the non-working one does, and the innermost child elements have popovers.  My intuition tells me that the problem lies somewhere in there.  I couldn't find any other questions with this exact problem.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="bar in foo.bars">
    <h4 class="row" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#bar-{{$index}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="bar-{{$index}}">{{bar.name}}</h4>
    <div id="bar-{{$index}}" class="collapse in">                                                   
        <div ng-repeat="barType in bar.types">                                                          
            <div class="col-xs-1 instance" ng-repeat="barChild in barType">
                <div class="bar-subcontainer">
                    <a class="center pointer" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" popover-placement="right" popover-template="'popover-template.html'" popover-trigger="click">
                       {{barChild.ID}}
                    </a>    
                </div>                                              
            </div>
        </div>                              
    </div>                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually the col-xs-1 class that you apply to each of the barChild divs. In particular, the style 'float: left;' that is inherited.

To test it, add style rule:

```
.instance { float:none; }
```

Of course that will fix the smooth collapse, but will break the existing layout. Perhaps you could use a table layout to re-create the desired UI.

Comment: Everything that you said would happen happened.  It fixed the animation but broke the column layout.  A table would work I suppose, but first I'm going to try to wrap the `.instance` class inside the `col-xs-1` class.

Comment: Well that didn't work.  At least I know what the problem is now though.

Comment: The table implementation worked.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The table implementation mentioned by @GPicazo worked.

**HTML**

```
<table>                                             
        <tr ng-repeat="barType in bar.types">                                                          
            <td class="col-xs-1 instance" ng-repeat="barChild in barType">
                <div class="bar-subcontainer">
                    <a class="center pointer" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" popover-placement="right" popover-template="'popover-template.html'" popover-trigger="click">
                       {{barChild.ID}}
                    </a>    
                </div>                                              
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The above is nested inside the outermost `ng-repeat` and the collapse from the original code.